# Let G(x)= $\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt$, where $G:[c,d]\rightarrow R$. Prove that G is differential on [c,d]

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$, a continous function, and $a,b:[c,d]\rightarrow [a,b$, two functions that are differentiable on $[c,d]$

Let G(x)= $\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt$, where $G:[c,d]\rightarrow R$. Prove that G is differential on [c,d] and that:

$$G'(x)=f(b(x))*b'(x)-f(a(x))*a'(x)$$

Now of course this is derived from the fundamental theory of calculus. Now, can I prove this without having to resort to using $\delta-\epsilon$?

Again, hints are preferential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is somewhat infelicitous; let's call the functions $\alpha\colon[c,d]\to[a,b]$ and $\beta\colon[c,d]\to[a,b]$, so you want to consider
$$
G(x)=\int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)}f(t)\,dt
$$
The fundamental theorem of calculus, together with the chain rule, tells you that $G$ is differentiable and
$$
G'(x)=f(\beta(x))\beta'(x)-f(\alpha(x))\alpha'(x)
$$

Let $F$ be an antiderivative for $f$ (it exists because $f$ is continuous); then
$$
G(x)=F(\beta(x))-F(\alpha(x))
$$
Differentiate both sides.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. I was assuming that the FTC already did most of the heavy work for this proof, and all that was left was to use the chain rule to show what we were looking for. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @RonaldB The FTC provides you with an antiderivative, and it's this point that makes the proof easier.